# Get returned object from Thread

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm writing a code that opens 3 Selenium Webdrivers.

```
from selenium import webdriver
b1 = webdriver.Firefox()
b2 = webdriver.Firefox()
b3 = webdriver.Firefox()
```

The browser loading takes a lot of time, and I want to load it parallel.
I though to use threading, but how can I return the b1,b2,b3 from thread?

I mean, if I have this function:

```
def open_browser():
  return webdriver.Firefox()
```

Threading with it will look like:

```
b1 = threading.Thread(target=open_browser, args=())
```

but the returned value, the browser instance, does not set into b1.

How should I do this?

Comment: of course not: `b1` is the Thread object just created. See [here](https://pymotw.com/2/threading/) for reference. BTW, I seriously doubt using threads would make things any better...

Comment: If you are unsatisfied because the Firefox is slow, I recommend you use the PhantomJS

Comment: @Pynchia I just want to load them parallel..

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#module-concurrent.futures). They should allow you to run code like this:

```
N = 3
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=N) as executor:
    # start three Firefoxes in parallel
    futures = [executor.submit(webdriver.Firefox) for i in range(N)]
    # wait for all of them to be started
    browsers = [f.result() for f in futures]
```

Answer (score -1):

Just put the variable outside the scope

```
import threading
from selenium import webdriver

b1 = None
b2 = None
b3 = None
b_list = [b1, b2, b3]
url_list = ['https://www.google.com.br/', 'http://stackoverflow.com/', 'https://www.youtube.com/']


def open_browser(b_index, url):
    b_list[b_index] = webdriver.Firefox()
    b_list[b_index].get(url)

thread_list = []
for index, url in zip(range(len(b_list)), url_list):
    thread_list.append(
        threading.Thread(target=open_browser, args=(index, url))
    )

for i in thread_list:
    i.start()

for i in thread_list:
    i.join()

print('finish')

for i in b_list:
    print(i.current_url)
```

Another way to optimize is to use [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/). It is faster than Firefox.